# Need to find and disable an email that may be coming from a module

Tags: users, emails

Drupal 7 question: There is an email that goes to users that seems to be produced by a module (on a role change) that is confusing to a specific client's users. They would like me to disable that specific email, but I have not been able to figure out where to do that.

I've gone through the users and roles and configuration for the module. I've done a search on the text in the site files (the snippets of text that do not have field-specific data) and come up empty.

So, generically, I'm wondering about how to disable emails from being sent if there doesn't seem to be a setting to do so in the dashboard. I would be happy to add more information here that is about the module specifically, but it seems that it would be helpful to have some generic pointers of where to look, in case the situation comes up in other modules, as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Rules module enabled, go and check the rules

```
/admin/config/workflow/rules
```

It's very likely that there is a rule that is sending the emails. So just disable it.

Comment: To the benefit of the OP understanding: Doesn't the Rules module use `drupal_mail()` to send emails?

Comment: I'm sure it does, but it's better to disable it through rules, if its using rules, than having to hack the module (^_^)

Comment: Revisiting Rules. I had checked rules before and there were no Rules listed. That didn't make sense because the related modules have rules. On further investigation, I found that Rules UI was not enabled, but Rules were!

Answer (score 0):

Search the module code for usages of 'drupal_mail'.

Comment: That did come up with one instance in a related module, but it was not relevant to the specific situation.